# How do I add text to a subsection in Go Present?

Tags: go, go-present

Given this Go presentation input code

```
Question on subsection

* Slide title

Here is a minimal go present slide.  Why is the slide subsection text
at the bottom of the slide?

** slide subsection

Hello, this text is part of the subsection.
```

I counterintuitively see "Hello..." immediately following "Here is..." with "slide subsection" at the bottom of the page.

**How do I make the "Hello..." text follow the subsection title?**

[image]

Comment: It's a long standing bug with the `present` tool (since 2013). Here's the relevant thread for the issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6846), slides were never intended to have subsections.

Ignore the `present` documentation referring to subsections and subsubsections.